# Developing in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

We have multiple projects in VB 6.0. Most of these projects are ActiveX DLL's. When developing, projects take a '.dll' reference of other projects, but this does not allow us to debug. So, for this we have to take a reference to the '.vbp' project. However, taking a project reference, means we are asked for binary compatibility.

During development, should we use project compatibility and build projects into DLL's for deployment?

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to reference the vbp during development, just make sure you keep binary compatibility on. If you do not, you'll make the registry into a nice mess and deployment will be a disaster. Keep in mind, however, even with binary compatibility on, every time you change the public interface of the DLL, you're creating a forward reference in the OLE entry in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

we have four levels of DLLS in the CAD/CAM software we use for my company's cutting machines. We handled this by making a compatibility directory that the PREVIOUS version's DLLs in it. With this we can continue to use binary compatibility.

The process looks like this.

- Compatibility has Revision 119 DLLs
  in it.
- We compile down Revision 120 and
  release it
- Copy the Revision 120 DLLs to the
  compatibility directory.
- Develop
- Test
- We Compile down Revision 121 and
  release it.
- Copy the Revision 121 DLLs to the
  compatibility directory.
- [repeat]

The main problem you need to watch out for is changes to the the lowest level of DLLs you use. Visual Basic 6 uses a #include statement in generating its internal type libraries. Doing will need to getting it confused over whether it is still binary compatible or not. Note you can see this by using the OLE View tool that comes with Visual Studio 6.

The solution to this problem is compile the low level DLL and immediately put it into the compatibility directory. The resulting internal typelibs for the higher level DLLs will now properly detect whether you are binary compatible or not.

Remember binary compatibile means all you can do is add a method or property. You can't change a existing method's name or argument list. (it's signature in COM terms)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to debug referencing a dll. Did you start the projects in the right order? Or you can add all/some dll into the same "Project Group" (*.vbg).